# How to bind data using Angular in my case?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am trying to create a tooltip based from from this post

[Angular-UI-Bootstrap custom tooltip/popover with 2-way data-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600603/angular-ui-bootstrap-custom-tooltip-popover-with-2-way-data-binding)

I successfully created the popup but I have trouble delivering the content to my popover.html

I added this to my script.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ian.bootstrap']);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.item = {
    title: 'Original Title',
    content:'content 1'  //newly added item
  };  
  $scope.text = 'Click me';
});
```

and I want to display it in my popover.html

```
<div class="popover-content">
     {{item.content}}
</div>
```

It doesn't show anything. Can someone help me about it? thanks a lot!

my plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/5pBZ9qq79OPl2tGEeYYV?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `ng-controller` in your `div` and then specify the controller name like so :

```
<div class="popover-content" ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    {{item.content}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the use cases, the basic syntax to create a custom directive.
For all the code samples in this page I started from the angular-seed template.
Starting from the angular-seed skeleton is quite easy to extract a model to begin to implement custom directives.

```
<html ngApp="myApp">

    ...

    <div my-first-directive></div>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>

    ...

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated working **<kbd>[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4GxBGQJ46WOVb0t1jSrQ?p=preview)</kbd>**

Basically you have to pass the attr `iantooltip-content` with the binding of the content item, not the raw text, and after in the directive pass in the directive isolate scope options the binding of the content like :

```
iantooltipContent: '='
```

Just change the appenToBody variable and you're done.

You should read the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for more infos about Angular directive :)